# Box shadow not working properly

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

Although I have ask the same question two times but I'm not getting any proper solution for this.I dont know what is wrong with my code. so here I'm posting the whole code (I know its against the community standard but seriously I want a solution for my problem and I request you guys to have a look at this and please keep patience) I'm new to web development field, please help me.

My problem is that I need to apply box shadow to #main-content-area to its top side and as well as left and right side (50% from top side)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
      #top-bar{
background-color:black;
color:white;
}

#txt-bar{
height:40px;
background-color:pink;
position:relative;
z-index:4;
}
#link-bar{

background-color:red;
height:40px;
z-index:4;
}
#image{
position:relative;
z-index:3;
}
.wrapper{
position:relative;
height: 100%;
width:100%;
}
#main-content-area{
position:relative;
background-color:white;
margin: -80px auto auto auto;
z-index:4;
border:1px solid red;
}
.halfshadow{
z-index:-1;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
box-shadow: 1000px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#footer{
background-color:green;
position:relative;
}


  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row" id="top-bar">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" >
   <h4> Some links </h4>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="txt-bar"><h1 >Greetings</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"  id="link-bar">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="image">
   <img src="header.png" class="img-responsive"/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="row" >
   <div class="col-sm-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8" id="main-content-area">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:green">
    <h3>Welcome </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="halfshadow"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-2" >
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" id="footer">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h4>some text........</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   < h4>some link </h4>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>     
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine, you didn't see any results because the `halfshadow` div on which you have applied the `box-shadow` doesn't have any content. Put there few words and the div aswell as the box-shadow will appear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [box shadow not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391849/box-shadow-not-working). Please don't open multiple questions for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It won't show. Because box shadow to the div element was empty. I just add some text and `margin-top`

```css
#top-bar{
background-color:black;
color:white;
}

#txt-bar{
height:40px;
background-color:pink;
position:relative;
z-index:4;
}
#link-bar{

background-color:red;
height:40px;
z-index:4;
}
#image{
position:relative;
z-index:3;
}
.wrapper{
position:relative;
height: 100%;
width:100%;
}
#main-content-area{
position:relative;
background-color:white;
margin: -80px auto auto auto;
z-index:4;
border:1px solid red;
}
.halfshadow{
  margin-top:20px;
z-index:-1;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px rgba(150, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#footer{
background-color:green;
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="top-bar">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" >
            <h4> Some links </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="txt-bar"><h1 >Greetings</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"  id="link-bar">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="image">
            <img src="header.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8" id="main-content-area">
                <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:green">
                <h3>Welcome </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="halfshadow">Shadow content</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="footer">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h4>some text........</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <   h4>some link </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  


</div>
```

Comment: I just told him the same thing. By the way, comment would be enough for such a trivial problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-content-area{
box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 50px;
background: white;
}
```

or you can go for it also

```
#main-content-area
 {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
background-color: yellow;
box-shadow: 15px 1px 5px #888888;
}
```

Comment: He didn't want the `box-shadow` property on `main-content-area` div.

Comment: I think that he is asking "My problem is that I need to apply box shadow to #main-content-area to its top side and as well as left and right side (50% from top side)"

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's just weird. His code says something completely different then his question is.

Comment: Guys,my question is that how could i add box shadow to the half part of #main-content-area and top side also. half part should be starting from top. just omit the halfshadow class.

Answer (score 0):

Explain box shadow for every thing here in my example the values are:
Horizontal Length:1px
Vertical Length:4px
Blur Radius:16px
Spread Radius:15px

The CSS:
box-shadow: 1px 4px 16px 15px rgba(82,43,136,1);

Comment: I need box shadow to half part only...i dont know how to solve this

Comment: Hey buddy ...
Just Go to this Site we all use this to make the look professional and of course for the boxshadow too ... 
Just visit once .
http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the `box-shadow` property to your `#main-content-area` div, you have to basically... add this property into `#main-content-area` div in your css file.

It will apply the shadow effect on left, right and bottom side:

```
box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 230, 0.5);
```

If you want the shadow to appear only on bottom and right side, use:

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 230, 0.5);
```

**Codepen**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmoNWJ

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
      #top-bar{
background-color:black;
color:white;
}

#txt-bar{
height:40px;
background-color:pink;
position:relative;
z-index:4;
}
#link-bar{

background-color:red;
height:40px;
z-index:4;
}
#image{
position:relative;
z-index:3;
}
.wrapper{
position:relative;
height: 100%;
width:100%;
}
#main-content-area{
position:relative;
background-color:white;
margin: -80px auto auto auto;
z-index:4;
border:1px solid red;
box-shadow : -10px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),10px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0px -10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);  
}
.halfshadow{
z-index:-1;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
box-shadow: 1000px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#footer{
background-color:green;
position:relative;
}


  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row" id="top-bar">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" >
   <h4> Some links </h4>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="txt-bar"><h1 >Greetings</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"  id="link-bar">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="image">
   <img src="header.png" class="img-responsive"/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="row" >
   <div class="col-sm-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8" id="main-content-area">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:green">
    <h3>Welcome </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="halfshadow"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-2" >
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" id="footer">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h4>some text........</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   < h4>some link </h4>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>     
</div>
</body>
</html>
```